# Upload Apk on Google drive using Circle CI (Continuous Integration) Android

Tags: android, continuous-integration, apk, google-drive-android-api

Unable to upload the **`APK`** on **`google drive`** using **`circle.yml`** file.

Below is the circle.yml file present in project directory.

```
general:
  branches:
    only:
      - /Feature_CircleCI/ # or regexes

  artifacts:
    - app/build/outputs/apk/

dependencies:
   pre:
   # Install the android packages
    - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "platform-tools,build-tools-25.0.2,android-25,sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-25,extra-android-support,extra-google-google_play_services,extra-google-m2repository,extra-android-m2repository"

test:
  post:
    - mkdir $CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS/apks
    - curl -L -o gdrive "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B3X9GlR6EmbnbURvYnVyVmNNX2M&export=download"; chmod 755 gdrive
    - ./gdrive --refresh-token "refresh_token_value" upload --parent "parent_id" app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk


  override:
        # Generate a debug-apk
        - ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

While uploading the APK on gdrive, an error is coming -

```
bash: line 1: ./gdrive: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Comment: I found the solution to this. I was giving the wrong url. The correct url to download gdrive is curl -L -o gdrive "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B3X9GlR6EmbnQ0FtZmJJUXEyRTA&export=download"; chmod +x gdrive